Maui MP3 file duration - MediaElement Duration reads 00:00
I am using the new dotnet maui MediaElement, and before letting my user pick an MP3 file to play, I want to list the tracks and their durations - in my case MP3 files. However unless you get the MediaElement to play the file, and wait for the mediaOpened event, the duration is zero, which is not helpful. Any ideas on how I can read MP3 file duration reliably on Maui cross platform ?
For windows the excellent nuget package nAudio works with 2 lines of code, but crashes on the iPhone.

Please search before posting

From the official document Properties, we could find that Duration Indicates the duration of the currently opened media. This is a read-only, bindable property. So, you can use this property to get the duration of currently opened media.

but crashes on the iPhone. And how can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

@Jessie:
These lines of code fail as I believe nAudio is trying to access a windows DLL - I actually do capture the exception, so it doesn't actually crash - just doesn't work:

using NAudio.Wave;
{
Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(szFullName);
TimeSpan duration = reader.TotalTime;
string szDuration = szDuration = duration.ToString(@"mm:ss");
LocalItem.Duration = szDuration;
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
string szLog = "Error e: " + e.Message ;
Debug.WriteLine(szLog);
}

@Jason - of course I searched and am aware it's on open which I stated wasn't very helpful. I was asking if there are other ways out there that work cross platform - it's also a plea to get MediaElement to do this by maybe having a Load function?

If you would like a change made to MediaElement, file an issue on its GitHub page, not here.  I saw several discussions in the linked serarch that offered alternate solutions

@Jason - apologies, I did go back through your suggested search and after initially thinking TagLib was C++ only, I did discover there was a c-sharp version which solved the issue, and I have posted the answer. Thanks for making me look again !

With apologies to Jason, I did go back through his suggested search and although I had thought TagLib was only C++, I discovered a C sharp version,and this solved my problem - as follows:
Download and install the nuget package TagLibSharp
My code was:
using TagLib;

var TagFile = TagLib.File.Create(MP3FileName);
TimeSpan duration = TagFile.Properties.Duration;
string Duration = Duration = duration.ToString(@"mm\:ss");

There was one minor problem in that the compiler then got confused as TagLib uses the term File
This can get confused with System.IO.File, so I had to be explicit when using File for actual file operations
